# Split Query Results Into there Own Table Depending on Same ID

Tags: php, sql

I am currently displaying a table full of results using the following:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_tasks_po");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='tdclass' width='100'>" . $row['TASK_ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass' width='100'>" . $row['QTY'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass' width='100'>" . $row['CODE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass' width='500'>" . $row['PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}                   
?>

</table>
```

This brings the following in:

```
| Task ID  |  Qty  |  Code  |  Description
| 1        |  200  |  AB1   |  Frame 1
| 1        |  350  |  AB2   |  Frame 2
| 2        |  100  |  AB3   |  Frame 3
| 2        |  120  |  AB4   |  Frame 4
| 2        |  300  |  AB5   |  Frame 5
```

Here's what I want and I'm not sure how I can do it.  I need a new table creating for each group of ID.  So for example:

```
TABLE ONE

| Task ID  |  Qty  |  Code  |  Description
| 1        |  200  |  AB1   |  Frame 1
| 1        |  350  |  AB2   |  Frame 2

TABLE TWO

| Task ID  |  Qty  |  Code  |  Description
| 2        |  100  |  AB3   |  Frame 3
| 2        |  120  |  AB4   |  Frame 4
| 2        |  300  |  AB5   |  Frame 5
```

I thought about grouping the results by task_id but had no joy and I've also thought about using an if statement but cannot for the life of me work out how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the results and reprint the header when task_id changes. Example:

```
<?
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_tasks_po ORDER BY TASK_ID");

$current_task_id = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($current_task_id != $row['TASK_ID'])
    {
        echo "</table><table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th width='100'>Task ID</th>";
        echo "<th width='100'>Qty</th>";
        echo "<th width='100'>Code</th>";
        echo "<th width='500'>Description</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $current_task_id = $row['TASK_ID'];
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass' width='100'>" . $row['TASK_ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass' width='100'>" . $row['QTY'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass' width='100'>" . $row['CODE'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdclass' width='500'>" . $row['PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>

</table>
```

Comment: That's what I've been looking for.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Good one. Although he specifically said he wanted _two tables_, so you might wanna add an `echo "</table><table>";` as well.

Comment: To split this into tables, where would I put the 'echo "</table><table>' as it is creating new tables for every row where I am putting it.  I am basically trying to add some text after every table now and struggling.

Comment: I changed my post and added the </table><table>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need two tables.  I think you need two result sets.  What you are looking for is a `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM b_tasks_po
WHERE id = 1;
```

If, indeed, you do want to create two tables (which as a general rule seems like a bad idea), then look into the `create table as` functionality in MySQL.

Comment: This wouldn't work.  The tasks are being generated on another area of the website and therefore I will never know the actual ID number, so can't perform a WHERE ID=1.  If that makes sense.

Comment: @AndyNaylor . . . No, it doesn't make sense to me.  But it looks like someone else answered your question.  Kudos to them.